# How can I display a result of dictionary from a IntegerField with choices?

Tags: python, django

In `stats.py` where I defined my function (`etat_sante` is an `IntegerField` of my model `JaarJaarRefugePikine` with choices `(1, u"Bonne Sante"), (2, u"Blessure"),...`).

```
def get_nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante():
    nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante = JaaJaarRefugePikine.objects.values('etat_sante')\
            .annotate(nb_jeunes=Count('etat_sante'))
    return nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante
```

in my template I have  :

```
    <h3>Repartition des jeunes par etat de sante a l'arrivee</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Etat sante</b></td>
            <td><b>Nombre</b></td>
        </tr>
        {% for jeune in nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ jeune.etat_sante }}</td>
            <td>{{ jeune.nb_jeunes }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

views.py :

```
    template_values = {'nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante': stats.get_nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante()}
```

and I have this result:

[image: Displayed table]

Comment: What's your question? What's the problem with what you currently have?

Comment: OP presumably wants to see 'Injured' rather than the magic number 2, 'Healthy' rather than 1, etc. Basically mapping int values to human-readable text.

Comment: @jarmod, but Injured and Healthy are not French are they?

Comment: @user1514631 No, they're not. I took the liberty of translating for the non-French speaking 95% of StackOverflow. Maybe I just added to the confusion!

Comment: @jarmod, I was going for a joke, but in all honesty i would like to help the OP and I know I could, but I really don't speak french and the example just confuses me. I'm also lazy, google translate is not an option.

Comment: Anyhow, I think the OP may need to create a class representing each object currently returned by nb_jeunes_par_etat_sante() and then add a get_description method to that class that returns the appropriate description for the object's etat_sante value.

Comment: I *think* OP is just asking for `{{ jeune.get_etat_sante_display }}`, a mixture of French and English that would have the Académie Française in fits, but it's hard to tell for sure.